Why am I getting "CP_CHECKPOINT_FILE_READ_FAILED ERROR 30004" in GridDB during backup or data synchronization?
I’m using GridDB to manage a distributed database cluster, and recently encountered the following error during backup or data synchronization between nodes:
30004 CP_CHECKPOINT_FILE_READ_FAILED ERROR
Execution of backup or cluster data synchronization failed. A failure may have occurred in the storage at the data file storage location.
Check whether a physical failure has occurred in storing the database file storage location. For all other cases, check with support as an internal error may have occurred.

I’m not sure how to resolve this error. I suspect it might be due to a physical failure at the storage location, but I’m unsure how to verify or troubleshoot this.
Here’s a simplified version of the code I’m using for data backup and synchronization:
from griddb_python import StoreFactory, GSException
import shutil

def perform_backup():
    try:
        # Connect to GridDB cluster
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store({
            "host": "239.0.0.1",
            "port": 41999,
            "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        })

        # Retrieve container
        container = gridstore.get_container("containerName")
        if container is None:
            raise Exception("Container not found")

        # Attempt data backup by copying files from the storage directory
        storage_path = "/var/lib/griddb/data"
        backup_path = "/backup/griddb/data"
        shutil.copytree(storage_path, backup_path)
        print("Data backup completed successfully")

    except GSException as e:
        print(f"Backup or synchronization failed: {e.what()}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_backup()

In this code:
I connect to a GridDB cluster and retrieve a container to access stored data.
I then attempt to back up the data by copying files from the GridDB data directory to a backup directory.
Here are some additional details about my setup:
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python Version: 3.8
GridDB Version: 4.5
Cluster Size: 5 nodes
Data Storage Path: /var/lib/griddb/data
Backup Storage Path: /backup/griddb/data
I'm looking for guidance on:
How to determine if there is a physical storage failure at the data file location.
Other possible reasons for the CP_CHECKPOINT_FILE_READ_FAILED ERROR 30004 during backups or synchronization.
Any best practices for managing backup storage locations and ensuring data integrity in GridDB.
Has anyone experienced this error with GridDB, or have any recommendations on how to diagnose and resolve it?
